# Как лучше присоединять файлы?

Tags: обсуждение

Иногда к вопросу или ответу требуется присоединить файл. Например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/698602/3380) я дал ссылку на PDF-документ, находящийся на другом сайте. Но на st.com документы часто перемещаются, и ссылки становятся недействительными. Существующие механизмы позволяют прикреплять лишь изображения, которые всё равно загружаются на сторонний ресурс. Как лучше поступить в данном случае?

Comment: Картинки хоть и на стороннем сайте, но с imgur у SO договоренность, что такие ссылки не тухнут.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Прикреплять его к ответу (как неотъемлемую часть) не стоит.

Если этот файл небольшого объёма или к ответу имеет отношение лишь небольшая его часть — нужное содержимое можно **перенести прямо внутрь ответа**. Текст, формулы, картинки. Соблюдая условия распространения материала, разумеется (он может быть под лицензией, требующей ссылки на первоисточник, указания автора, или чего ещё).

Если **файл большого объёма** — **ответ не должен на него опираться вообще**. Если вопрос охватывает весь этот файл, то он слишком общий и должен быть закрыт для уточнения. После которого необходимости прикреплять к ответу весь файл уже не будет.

Можно приложить ссылку на файл "для дальнейшего погружения в тему". Умрёт ссылка — не шибко жалко, если ответ самодостаточен. А если не самодостаточен — подлежит тревогам "не является ответом", как ответ-ссылка и последующему удалению.

Comment: Ага, уже предвижу вопросы типа "вот файл модуля, почините!".